# Need macro to cycle through all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro and I need it to perform the same operation on all the worksheets in the workbook, not just the active one. I've tried tons of different stuff, but I don't have much experience with excel so I'm not having much luck.

Here's the macro.

```
Sub Tester()

Dim c As Range, rngMerge As Range

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, 100).Cells
    Set rngMerge = c.MergeArea
    If rngMerge.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        c.UnMerge
        rngMerge.Value = rngMerge.Cells(1).Value
    End If
    c.Value = JoinUp(c.Resize(3, 1), "_")
Next c
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A3").EntireRow.Delete
End Sub


Function JoinUp(rng As Range, Optional Delim As String = "") As String
Dim c As Range, rv As String
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
        rv = rv & IIf(Len(rv) > 0, Delim, "") & c.Value
    End If
Next c
JoinUp = rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 Sub ProcessAll()
   Dim sht as worksheet
   for each sht in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      ProcessSheet sht 
   next sht
 End sub


 Sub ProcessSheet(sht as worksheet)

 Dim c As Range, rngMerge As Range

 For Each c In sht.Range("A1").Resize(1, 100).Cells
    Set rngMerge = c.MergeArea
    If rngMerge.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        c.UnMerge
        rngMerge.Value = rngMerge.Cells(1).Value
    End If
    c.Value = JoinUp(c.Resize(3, 1), "_")
 Next c
 sht.Range("A2:A3").EntireRow.Delete
End Sub


Function JoinUp(rng As Range, Optional Delim As String = "") As String
  Dim c As Range, rv As String
  For Each c In rng.Cells
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
        rv = rv & IIf(Len(rv) > 0, Delim, "") & c.Value
    End If
  Next c
  JoinUp = rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

or use

```
dim sht as worksheet

for each sht in thisworkbook.sheets
      debug.print sht.name
next sht
```

Comment: Starting an answer with "or use" makes it look really weird, especially if it gets upvotes and floats up to the top... Ironically, this probably ensures it won't stay up there very long!

Comment: Did I say your answer was wrong? Or your code should be more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

To loop over all the sheets in a workbook, you can use:

```
   dim i as Integer

   For i = 1 To ActiveWorkBook.WorkSheets.Count
       ' do stuff
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i) ....
   Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet1")).Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
```

or if you want to cycle through:

```
For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Next aSheet
```